# Unable to update TableLayout from within Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-tablelayout

I'm working on an app that lets the user take a quiz and records all quiz scores to be referenced later if so desired. I'm building a fragment that allows the user to view this record in a TableLayout. I need to dynamically add rows, so I'm trying to create a way to add rows during the onCreateView method of the fragment. However, these rows never show up in the app, despite being shown as children of the table in the debugger. I've tried detaching then re-attaching the fragment, but that never helps. I'd be very grateful to be able to figure this one out.

This is the fragment:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;

    public void addEntryToTable(TableLayout table, String user, String date, String score) {

        QuizHistoryTableRow row = new QuizHistoryTableRow(getContext(), user, date, score);
        table.addView(row);
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);

        TableLayout table = root.findViewById(R.id.quiz_history_table);
        addEntryToTable(table, "user", "date", "score");

        return root;
    }
}
```

And here is the custom table row:

```
public class QuizHistoryTableRow extends TableRow {

    public QuizHistoryTableRow(Context context, String user, String date, String score){
        super(context);

        TextView userView = new TextView(context);
        userView.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        userView.setText(user);
        userView.setTextColor(0);
        userView.setTextSize(22);

        TextView dateView = new TextView(context);
        dateView.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        dateView.setText(date);
        dateView.setTextColor(0);
        dateView.setTextSize(22);

        TextView scoreView = new TextView(context);
        scoreView.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        scoreView.setText(score);
        scoreView.setTextColor(0);
        scoreView.setTextSize(22);

        addView(userView);
        addView(dateView);
        addView(scoreView);
    }

}
```

Comment: `userView.setTextColor(0)` – Zero is transparent. If you meant for that to be black, it would be `0xff000000` instead. However, it would be better to use [`Color.BLACK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#BLACK).

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for the response, I changed it to Color.Black, but it's for some reason it's still not showing up. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, yeah, it's the `LayoutParams`; at least, that's one more thing. A `View`'s `LayoutParams` need to be of its parent's type, because it's information for the parent to know how to lay out that child. In this case, your `TextView`s are in a `TableRow`, so they need `TableRow.LayoutParams`, not `TableLayout.LayoutParams`. Sometimes, certain types of `LayoutParams` can be successfully converted to another type, but `TableLayout` is very finicky about it. Since you're inside a `TableRow` class there, you can just remove `TableLayout.` from the beginning of those constructor calls.

Comment: Also, though this wouldn't cause the current issue, I would also mention that whenever you use weights, the dimension that corresponds to the orientation should have a value of `0`. That is, since these are horizontal, the width should be `0`. So, altogether: `new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f)`.

Comment: @MikeM. That worked! Thank you so much, I've been pulling my hair out over this for a while.

Comment: No problem. If you would like to, please feel free to post an answer to show the changes you've made, and maybe to throw in a little of the explanation. The system won't let you accept your own answer for two days, but please do so when you can, so your question will show as resolved. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, it was an issue with `TableLayout.LayoutParams` vs `TableRow.LayoutParams`. Thanks to Mike M. for the answer.

Modified fragment:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;

    public TableRow getNewEntry(Context context, String user, String date, String score) {

        QuizHistoryTableRow row = new QuizHistoryTableRow(context, user, date, score);
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return row;
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);

        TableLayout table = root.findViewById(R.id.quiz_history_table);
        TableRow row = getNewEntry(getContext(), "user", "date", "score");
        table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return root;
    }

}
```

And the modified table row:

```
public class QuizHistoryTableRow extends TableRow {

    public QuizHistoryTableRow(Context context, String user, String date, String score){
        super(context);

        TextView userView = new TextView(context);
        userView.setText(user);
        userView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        userView.setTextSize(22);
        userView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

        TextView dateView = new TextView(context);
        dateView.setText(date);
        dateView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        dateView.setTextSize(22);
        dateView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

        TextView scoreView = new TextView(context);
        scoreView.setText(score);
        scoreView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        scoreView.setTextSize(22);
        scoreView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

        addView(userView);
        addView(dateView);
        addView(scoreView);
    }

}
```